# Show that a differential equation has a particular solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you prove that the equation $y''+k^2y=R(x)$ has a solution $y_1$ given by $$y_1=\frac{1}{k}\int_0^x R(t)\sin(k(x-t))dt$$

Comment: The simplest way is to plug in the solution and see if it satisfies the differential equation.

Comment: I suspect you could prove that using Laplace transforms and the convolution theorem.

Comment: There are three approaches: 1) verification by differentiation 2) [Green's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function) 3) Laplace transform and convolution.

Comment: In fact the most formal way is to prove it by [variation of parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_variation_of_parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Verifying a solution is (relatively) simple. Just plug it in, plug it in....

Actually *finding* a solution can be quite a bit more difficult.

Comment: How is this helpful? The differentiation of the above is not *that* simple! =)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff How is it not simple to someone studying differential equations?

Comment: @GitGud You would be very surprised...

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia article on Differentiation Under the Integral Sign, or maybe the one about the Leibniz Rule. (They are about the same thing.) I think you will not find the calculation difficult.

Comment: The first derivative should turn out to be $\int_0^x R(t)\cos(k(x-t))\,dt$, since one of the terms when you differentiate nicely disappears. The second derivative has two terms.

Comment: @Peter: I did say *relatively* simple. I wouldn't expect beginning calculus students to have any idea what to do, but I'd hope that anyone assigned such a problem would have the machinery in place to do it. Of course, if it's a self-study case and this is beyond the OP's ken, I hope they'll point that out.

Comment: @André Nicolas, there is also a factor of $k$ in front of it.

Comment: @DoctorDan: Not at all. The whole thing started with a factor of $\frac1k$ attached.

Comment: @DoctorDan: I do not think there is.

Comment: @André Nicolas True, the derivative itself does have it but it's cancelled out by $\frac{1}{k}$ in front of it. The way it was phrased initially is ambiguous.

Comment: Fair enough. =)

Answer (score 0):

The full version of the general solution of the corresponding ODE done by [variation of parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_variation_of_parameters) is $y=C_1\sin kx+C_2\cos kx+\sin kx\int_0^x\dfrac{R(x)\cos kx}{k}dx-\cos kx\int_0^x\dfrac{R(x)\sin kx}{k}dx$

Note that the general solution can also rewrite as

$y=C_1\sin kx+C_2\cos kx+\dfrac{\sin kx}{k}\int_0^xR(t)\cos kt~dt-\dfrac{\cos kx}{k}\int_0^xR(t)\sin kt~dt$

$y=C_1\sin kx+C_2\cos kx+\dfrac{1}{k}\int_0^xR(t)(\sin kx\cos kt-\cos kx\sin kt)~dt$

$y=C_1\sin kx+C_2\cos kx+\dfrac{1}{k}\int_0^xR(t)\sin(k(x-t))~dt$

The particular solution part is $y_1=\dfrac{1}{k}\int_0^xR(t)\sin(k(x-t))~dt$